# Is this UIImage data reader thread safe?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiimage, thread-safety

Or this code can be executed in a background thread safely?

```
    CGImageRef cgImage;
    CGContextRef context;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    // Sets the CoreGraphic Image to work on it.
    cgImage = [uiImage CGImage];

    // Sets the image's size.
    _width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    _height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    // Extracts the pixel informations and place it into the data.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    _data = malloc(_width * _height * 4);
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(_data, _width, _height, 8, 4 * _width, colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Adjusts position and invert the image.
    // The OpenGL uses the image data upside-down compared commom image files.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, _height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Clears and ReDraw the image into the context.
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, _width, _height));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, _width, _height), cgImage);

    // Releases the context.
    CGContextRelease(context);
```

How to acheive the same result, if not?

(My problem is that I can't see my OpenGL textures based on the output buffer of this method, if it runs in the background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have trouble with running this code on a separate thread from GL's like this. Even if it would work you might encounter half drawn images/textures. You could avoid this by creating a double buffer:
Your "_data" should be allocated only once and should hold 2 raw image data buffers. Then just create 2 pointers defined as foreground and background buffer (void *fg = _data[0], void *bg = _data[1] to begin with). Now when your method collects data from CGImage to bg just swap the pointers (then void *fg = _data[1], void *bg = _data[0] or the other way around)
Now your GL thread should fill your texture with data on fg (same thread as drawing).

Also you might need some locking mechanisms:

1. Before you push data to texture you should lock "buffer swap" and
   unlock it after the push.
2. You will probably want to know if the
       buffer has been swapped and only push fg data to texture in such
       case.

Also note that if you call GL methods on more then 1 thread you will have trouble in most cases.

Comment: I like this answer, but I can't understand it entirely.

Comment: Is this something like "retaining" the buffer for a while? I'm creating a UIImageDataParser instance every time I want to push an image to the texture, so the buffers should not "mix up". Maybe I'm simply release the buffer to early?

Comment: I tried to release the data object on the background thread, but no result.

Comment: No, it is not about retaining. You should have at least 2 buffers, you write image data to background buffer and present the foreground buffer data to texture. If you have/need more buffers and allocate them for every image as you do, you just need to send some message to your main GL thread that it should push those data to texture WHEN the background thread finished working on those data.. When to release a specific data may differ..

Comment: A much simple solution: Get AVCaptureSession callbacks on the main thread. :) That works well.

Comment: That might do as well. Though you said nothing about your data format. You can't use AVCaptureSession with a set of images and the code you showed only has CGImage as input..

Answer (score 0):

That looks OK to me, assuming that `uiImage`, `_width`, `_height` and `_data` aren't being manipulated from another thread at the same time. (Assuming you're using iOS 4 and above.)

Are you uploading the texture to OpenGL on the background thread? If so, that's probably the problem (since a given OpenGL context should only be accessed from a single thread at a time).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't access UIKit (or similar frameworks) (directly or indirectly) and as long as you don't access the variables in your code from multiple threads, it's OK.